# Restart a service after failure

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I have several services running, sometimes the service will crash, and I need a way to automaticaly restart the service. In the screenshot beneath there is a tab where I can controll the behaviour of the service, if it crashed:

[image]

Is there any parameter I can pass to the `Start-Service` operation in powershell, to define the behaviour if the service crashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with `Start-Service`. Try the `sc failure` command http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742019.aspx.